# Function to Map `[a] -> [[a]]`

Tags: haskell

Given `[1,2,3]`, I wrote the following to get `[[1],[2],[3]]`:

```
ghci> map return [1,2,3] :: [[Int]]
[[1],[2],[3]]
```

Is this usage of `return` idiomatic in Haskell? I'm asking since I could've also used `pure` instead.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see any problem with this. I guess the question could be one of declaring your intent to your reader:

by using `return`, you very much tell the reader that you are going to work with the list `monad`;

by using `pure` you would make them understand your decision in terms of `applicative`;

by using `(:[])`, they would simply think that you want to turn a list into a list of singletons.